# Remove Comma when posting number to SQL Error:System.InvalidOperationException:

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I remove a comma from the value when posting back to SQL? My SQL field is decimal but sometimes a value in the user will enter 10,000 and not 10000 so the post fails. So the strange this is I get an error message:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The ViewData item that has the key 'TypeOf' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.'

Which happens with a comma is put in Amount - without a comma in amount all is fine?

Thanks,
EB

```
  <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TypeOf, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "required control-label col-md-2" })
      <div class="col-md-10">
          @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TypeOf, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.TypesOfLoan, null, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TypeOf, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
  </div>
```

View:

```
     @Html.(model => model.Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:110px" } })
```

CS:

```
   public Nullable<decimal> Amount { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult CreateOrder(Order newOrder)
    {


       if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Orders.Add(newOrder);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Orders");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(newOrder);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user can add commas then it is no longer a decimal, which means your field is a text or varchar.

***NOTE*** You can stop the user from entering the comma or any other funny character at all

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Amount, new {@type="number"})
```

One of the things you can do is to use string replace and the parse to double

To replace the comma use

```
var amount = amount_input.Replace(',', '');
```

to parse to double use

```
var amount_as_double = double.Parse(amount, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

**EDIT**

looking at your question, I would not know if you are using `@Html.TextBoxFor` or and also no know how you are positing the form to the controller.

if your controller method looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Model model)
{
    //let's say no1 is decimal, model.no1 is going to be 0 if the user enters a comma and string.Replace is not going to work
    var amount = model.no1;   
    ...     
}
```

but of you are using something like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection)
{
    var amount = collection["Amount"].Replace(',', '')
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Would this go in the controller?

Comment: @EbertB see edits, basically for you to be able to receive a comma from the view means you are receiving it as a string, it is the string that you have to replace and cast to you decimal model

Comment: For some reason I can not get that to work. I updated my full controller. It does not like the .Replace. Any thoughts?

Comment: Replace is for string and not decimals. you need to change you model.Account to a string. but I would suggest you prevent the user for entering it at all

Comment: Ok. Thanks - crazy question - there is probably no way to just automatically show the , when they are typing in a number but only for show - not for posting?